# In horizontal scroll view the image centers by it's own. I need it to be centercropped

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

Currently the layout looks this way: 
https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/2IYgIygCi.png
I want it to look this way BUT the image to be horizontally scrollable:
https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/2IYsV5rzd.png

```
                <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/definition4_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3">

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="160dp"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/plsquadron" />
                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="@string/definition4_1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

For some reason it automatically centers the image. What's the solution?

Comment: Shouldn't scaleType be set in the ImageView?

Comment: @Micha Yes. it is, I fixed the code

Comment: and it looks like on a first screenshot

Comment: no answer... :(